# How to convert a List<Dictionary<string,string>> object to a List<object> to bind to a Datagrid?

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` object (the Keys in the Dict in each list object are the same), and I want to convert it to a `List<object>`, which can be binded to a Datagrid with manually generate columns. This will make each `Dictionary<string,string>` in the original list object be a row in the datagrid, and the properties on the object expected to bind are the Keys in the Dictionary.

Many thanks,

Wei

Comment: Not clear - what are the properties on the Object you expect to bind?

Comment: The properties on the object expected to bind are the Keys in the Dictionary. Thanks

Comment: Do you know all of the dictionary keys at compile time, or not?

Comment: No, I will extract them out at runtime.

Comment: Can you post an input/output sample? that would help understanding you request much better.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like

```
   <ListView Name="selectedPeople"
                  Width="480"
                  Height="200"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Maps,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
                                        Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Broadcast call targets">
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" Header="ID" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Description" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content=" X " IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>





  public partial class Listviewsamples : Window
    {
        public Listviewsamples()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Maps = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> item = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                item.Add(i.ToString(), " Item " + i.ToString());
                Maps.Add(item);
            }
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>> Maps { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: What is Window that Listviewsamples inherited? Is it a user control.

Comment: its not usercontrol its widnow type a similar to Form in winforms.

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest way for you is to create a table and populate it like that:
Let's assume the list named lst

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

foreach (var col in lst[0].Keys)
{
     table.Columns.Add(col, typeof(string));
}

foreach (var dict in lst)
{
     var row = table.NewRow();

     foreach (var data in dic)
     {
         row[data.Key] = data.Value;
     }

     table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

And all is left to do now is bind that table to a DataGrid!